# Two bitmaps in one imageview with different scaletype

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, scaletype

Hello I have a simple problem..

I need put two different bitmaps into one imageview. but One bitmaps must be on `ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY` and second on `ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER`

I found some methods from internet but all put with same scaletype.

Thanks for advice.

i need in imageview have this..  (image no pageview..)

[image]

////////// for explain why I need.

```
@Override public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
    ImageView img= new ImageView(view.getContext());
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(listKone.get(pozicia).getCestaObrazok(), img);

    //
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(listKone.get(pozicia).getCestaObrazok(), img2);


    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) img2.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    } catch (NullPointerException e){
    }



    while ((drawable==null)||(bitmap==null)) {
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(listKone.get(pozicia).getCestaObrazok(), img2); // Default options will be used

        drawable = (BitmapDrawable) img2.getDrawable();
        bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    }
    Bitmap blurred = blurRenderScript(act, bitmap, 25);



    view.addView(img, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    return img;
}
```

**return img;** I need Bitmap blurred and Bitmap Bitmap in one Imageview. But bitmap Blured FIT_XY and bitmap bitmap center. I need get view like in image ↑

Comment: What do you mean 2 bitmaps? At the same time or you need to switch between them?

Comment: on the same time =>  bitmaps in background (FIT_XY) have blureffect and bitmaps FIT_CENTER is normal.. without effect.

Comment: you cant set scaletype to the background. You can use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html  just set different android:gravity properties to the different bitmaps

Comment: i put image vhat i knowing.

Comment: I think what you are seeing is a viewpager with a base pageradapter and imageviews on each page. It also has been setup with a viewpager indicator. It's not an imageview that you are seeing.

Comment: yes, but I have viewpager.. and in method which create viewpagerview need return one img. but i need 2 img in one. because blur effect and normal image. I put creator view in viewpager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find method which I edited..

```
public static Bitmap CombineImages(Bitmap background, Bitmap foreground)  {

    int width = (int) act.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.imageH);
    int height = (int) act.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.imageH);
    Bitmap cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);
    background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, width, height, true);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);

    float Fwidth = foreground.getWidth();
    float Fheight = foreground.getHeight();

    if (Fheight>Fheight){
        Fwidth=(height/Fheight) * Fwidth;
        Fheight=height;
        foreground = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(foreground,(int) Fwidth,(int) Fheight, true);
    }

    if (Fheight<=Fheight){
        Fheight=(width/Fwidth)*Fheight;
        Fwidth=width;
        foreground = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(foreground,(int) Fwidth,(int) Fheight, true);
    }

    float top = (height-Fheight)/2;
    float left = (width-Fwidth)/2;

    comboImage.drawBitmap(foreground, left, top, null);

    return cs;
}
```

Have you better solution write. Ad iterim use this solution. But If in future will have more images will be Unneffective.

Answer (score 0):

use two imageview one over one.

Comment: I was to, but now I need all in one imageview. 
I need return imageview one imageView.

Comment: you can use any layout with setting backgound as the 1 image Or use RelativeLayout when you use relativelayout it allow you to put one view on another so you can put one imageview over another and if you want transparency you can do that as well

Answer (score 0):

```
    <layer-list>
   <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/bitmap1"
            android:gravity="fill" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/bitmap2"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You can use LayerDrawable like this to set two image on on another, then set them in ImageView